# Chat Event Reminders come from the wrong site

Tags: bug, chat, email, chat-event, parent-user

It seems that chat event reminders are sent from the chat user's parent site rather than the event room's parent site.

E.g. [this event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/52405/the-apl-orchard?tab=schedule#meeting-2520) belongs under Code Golf Stack Exchange, while "mi yodeya" is the logo for Judaism Stack Exchange which is [my chat user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/130368/adam) parent site:
[image: reminder email]